# How to alternate between button click even handlers

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, desktop-application

I am creating a desktop application that adds/edits users. Both functions will use the same inputs however each function will require different click handlers to update data and to insert new data into my database however I want to utilize the same buttons

Is their a way I can assign different click handlers to the same button?

Comment: You can add/remove event (click) handlers with **+=** and **-=**  Or are you thinking of something else?  I don't quite understand why you would have to change the event handlers ...

Comment: Does the text of the button change at the same time you want the click event handler to change?

Comment: Pretty unclear why you want to make this convoluted.  Just use *one* event handler and use an if() statement inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can,

```
//Register both handlers within constructor
button1.Click += new EventHandler(InsertOperationHandler);
button1.Click += new EventHandler(UpdateOperationHandler);
```

-

```
private void InsertOperationHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}


private void UpdateOperationHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is as follows:

```
public void displayEditButtons()
{
    buttonPeopleOne.Text = "Save Changes";
    this.buttonPeopleOne.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.buttonPeopleOneClear_Click);
    this.buttonPeopleOne.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonPeopleOneSave_Click);

        buttonPeopleTwo.Text = "Delete User";
        this.buttonPeopleTwo.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.buttonPeopleTwoNext_Click);
        this.buttonPeopleTwo.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonPeopleTwoDelete_Click);

        //change other controls to match the function context
        buttonPeopleChangeFunction.Visible = true;
        this.labelPeopleFunctionHeader.Text = "Edit Current User";
    }

    public void displayAddButtons()
    {
        buttonPeopleOne.Text = "Clear";
        this.buttonPeopleOne.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.buttonPeopleOneSave_Click);
        this.buttonPeopleOne.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonPeopleOneClear_Click);


        buttonPeopleTwo.Text = "Add Contact";
        this.buttonPeopleTwo.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.buttonPeopleTwoDelete_Click);
        this.buttonPeopleTwo.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonPeopleTwoNext_Click);

        //change other controls to match the function context
        buttonPeopleChangeFunction.Visible = false;
        this.labelPeopleFunctionHeader.Text = "Add New User";
```

}

I simply call the different methods when I need to change the buttons